# Java: Way to apply styles on current target

Tags: java, actionscript-3, events, javafx-2

Is there a method to **apply styles** or transformation **to a component** **when** targeted it with an **event** (e.g.: mouse_click) like in AS3?

AS3 example use:

```
...
event.currentTarget.setX(50);
...
```

In my code, I do compare all the targeted components to know on any one of them I should apply the style.
Like this:

```
    ...
    If(event.getTarget().equals(lbl_menu1))
    {
lbl_menu1.setLayoutX(50);
}
    else If(event.getTarget().equals(lbl_menu2))
    {
lbl_menu2.setLayoutX(50);
}
    ...
```

But I feel this is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do compare all the targeted components

Why are you doing that? You aren't doing it in As3 either.

```
event.getTarget().setLayoutX(50);
```

is the equivalent line in `Java`. To make it work, you have to cast `event.getTarget()` to some type that has a method `.setLayoutX(50)`.

Only call the method if the cast succeeds.